# Tkinter mainloop and while loop

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, program-entry-point

Hi I've programmed a simple Othello game and am now moving on to the area of programming I know nothing about, the GUI. For the time being I've managed to display the starting screen of the game and also get response from the GUI when I press the tiles on the board. The problem is that I haven't managed to update the window when the user presses it to place a tile. The problem I believe is situated in my main loop:

```
def main():
    GRID_SIZE = 4
    grid = Grid(GRID_SIZE)
    grid.start_game()
    player = 2
    ai = False
    cors = [None]*2
    in_game = True
    root = Tk()
    root.wm_title("Reversi")
    grid_frame = GridFrame(root, grid, player)
    while in_game:
        player = decide_player(grid, player)
        grid_frame.display("<Button-1>", grid)
        if player == 0:
            end(grid)
            in_game =False
            break
        if ai and player == 2:
            cors = grid.ai()
        else:
            cors = grid_frame.cors
        grid.place_tile(cors, player)
    root.mainloop()

main()
```

Is it even a thing to have a GUI main loop in  main loop for the functionality like this. All help is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Could be `cors = grid_frame.cors` -> `cors = grid_frame.cors()` Hard to say without the code of GridFrame.

Comment: This is not how GUI's work. Mainloop is to keep the window on the screen and update it as neccesary. If you were to program a game without the GUI the while loop is great (I think this is called sentinel conntrolled program) and the if statements move the game forward, while in a GUI events move the program forward like a button press, widget enter (mouse enters a widget), leaves, etc. From your description I was unable to image what program and game you are trying to achieve so I can't write a straight answer.

Comment: That feels more sensible, let me give the code another try with that approach and see what I come up with, thanks